# Python Selenium capture captcha in a scroll down page

Tags: python, selenium

I want to capture captcha code with python and selenium. So far I have this:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#imagecpt")
loc, size  = elem.location, elem.size
left, top     = loc['x'], (loc['y'] - 587)
width, height = size['width'], size['height']
box = (int(left), int(top), int(left+width), int(top+height))
screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(screenshot)))
captcha = img.crop(box)
captcha.save('captcha.png', 'PNG')
```

The code is working but there is a small problem, the top position returned by `elem.location` is complete position in website.

To capture the captcha code in my website I need to scroll down the page, as Selenium takes screenshot only for the visible part of the website and the top size returned by `elem.location` is not valid.

To solve the scrolling problem I am using a *hardcoded* value `- 587`. How can I rewrite the code without this hardcoded value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ActionChains.move_to_element()` method to scroll to the captcha.

Also, take a look at the [`location_once_scrolled_into_view`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.location_once_scrolled_into_view) in the Selenium documentation as it may be helpful.

> THIS PROPERTY MAY CHANGE WITHOUT WARNING. Use this to discover where
>   on the screen an element is so that we can click it. This method
>   should cause the element to be scrolled into view.
>
> Returns the top lefthand corner location on the screen, or None if the
>   element is not visible.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#imagecpt")

action_chain = ActionChains(driver)
action_chain.move_to_element(elem)
action_chain.perform()

loc, size = elem.location_once_scrolled_into_view, elem.size
left, top = loc['x'], loc['y']

width, height = size['width'], size['height']
box = (int(left), int(top), int(left + width), int(top + height))

screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(screenshot)))

captcha = img.crop(box)
captcha.save('captcha.png', 'PNG')
```